# Best Structure text to Translate on Crowdin

Tags: text, localization, format, crowdin

i'm working on a Location Fan Based of a videogame and for now i have a TXT with this structure :

```
<ID1>\t<ID2>\t<ID3>\t<ID4>\t"<stringToTranslate>"
<ID1>\t<ID2>\t<ID3>\t<ID4>\t"<stringToTranslate>"
<ID1>\t<ID2>\t<ID3>\t<ID4>\t"<stringToTranslate>"
<ID1>\t<ID2>\t<ID3>\t<ID4>\t"<stringToTranslate>"
```

I need to create a formatted file to translate and use the platform Crowdin ...
But I don't know what kind of structure to create, if to make a json, an ini, an xml, because then I have to create a script to convert my txt into this new type.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Any key-value file type would do the trick I believe - JSON format is a good choice (looks like you have multiple string IDs, so nested JSON will be perfect in terms of the structure)